# Compute Probability with random draws without replacement for certain order

Tags: probability

I would like to know if the solution to the problem is correct. If not, could you please explain the reasoning?

There are 7 white balls and 6 black balls in a bag. We draw without replacement. What is the probability that the first and third are white and second and fourth are black?

Here's my answer:

```
P(W for first position) = 7/13
P(B for second position = 6/13
P(W for third position) = 6/13
P(B for fourth position) = 5/13

So, the total probability is: 
(7/13)(6/13)(6/13)(5/13) = 0.0441 or 4.41%
```

Does this make sense? When I run the simulation, I get 0.0735. So, why is there a discrepancy?

```
# Initialize success, sims and urn
success, sims = 0, 50000
urn = ['w']*7 + ['b']*6

for _ in range(sims):
    # Draw 4 balls without replacement
    draw = np.random.choice(urn, replace=False, size=4)
    # Count the number of successes
    if (draw[0] == 'w') & (draw[1] == 'b') & (draw[2] == 'w') & (draw[3] == 'b'):
        success +=1

print("Probability of success = {}".format(success/sims))
```

Comment: Unclear question:  Do you mean that *all* the conditions must be held, or are you asking two separate questions?  Is your question merely:  What is the probability that the initial sequence of four balls is WBWB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is without replacement so the denominator shouldn't stay at 13 ...
$$ P(w, 1) = \frac 7{13}
\\  P(b, 2) = \frac 6{12} 
\\  P(w, 3) = \frac 6{11} 
\\  P(b, 4) = \frac 5{10}  $$
total probability is $\frac{1260}{17160} \approx 0.073$

Comment: Why is $P(w,1) = 6/13$?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork - it should not have been, I have edited to correct, thanks.

Comment: Oh... so I was first with the correct answer, and you were second with an incorrect answer, but the OP accepted yours.  (Oh well....)

Comment: I upvoted you myself because I realized that

Answer (score 1):

You didn't change the number of available balls in successive selections:

$$\frac{7}{13} \frac{6}{12} \frac{6}{11} \frac{5}{10} = 0.0734266.$$